# what does this mark mean on reed switch?

Tags: switches, reed-switch

I have some used reed switches with no datasheets. all of them have a black mark on one side. I want to know what does this mark mean?

[image]

Comment: A better picture would help a lot! It'd be important to know whether the dots are inside or outside. If inside: it could be some dot of [getter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter) metal to remove gases  (oxigen, nitrogen)that otherwise would react with (damage) arcing electrodes.

Comment: @Curd dot is a color on outside, all of reed switches have this mark on a same location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't.  Have  a broader look at reeds from other sources.  I have  a bunch of them here, and install them professionally for burglar alarms.  They either have no markings, or sometimes the manufacturer's details.  They don't have little black dots.  Can I suggest Google Images "reed switch"?  You'll see loads of examples, all without black dots. A reed switch is symmetric, non directional or un polarised.  They work either way round so don't require one end to be marked.

As to a getter.  No.  Getters are only for maintaining vacuum.  A reed switch contains an inert gas (typically nitrogen). The [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) mentions high voltage reed switches that operate in a vacuum, but I don't think that this is one of those.

It could be a testing mark, perhaps maybe. Could also be a spider.

Answer (score 0):

A normal reed switch should not be orientation dependant.

The paint dot is most likely a manufacturer model code designation.

However a [SPDT reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch#/media/File:Reedswitch.PNG) has one non (or less) magnetic terminal at the two wire end (the NC terminal).

A normally closed reed switch often is a SPDT type with the NO terminal cut short.  In this type the two end wires may have different magnetic characteristics and a dot might provide some strange value.  The pictured device looks like a normal NO switch.

While the picture does not show any difference it is possible that in a switch where one terminal is mobile and the other rigid a manufacturer might see fit to mark the relevant end, again I cannot see any use for this information.